# Puppet gives error: "Illegal relationship operand, can not form a relationship with an Undef Value."

Tags: puppet

When running this:

```
$ramdisk = '/never-save-to-disk'
$keyfile = "${ramdisk}/test.key"
$encryption_key = undef

file {
  [
    $ramdisk,
  ]:
  ensure => directory,
  owner  => 'root',
  group  => 'root',
}
mount { $ramdisk:
  ensure  => 'mounted',
  device  => 'null',
  fstype  => 'ramfs',
  options => 'defaults',
  dump    => 0,
  pass    => 0,
}
~> if ($encryption_key != undef) and ($encryption_key != '') {
   file { $keyfile:
    content => $encryption_key,
    path    => $keyfile,
    owner   => 'database',
    group   => 'database',
    mode    => '0600',
    require => File[$ramdisk],
  }
}
```

Puppet gives the error "Error: Evaluation Error: Illegal relationship operand, can not form a relationship with an Undef Value. A Catalog type is required. (file: /tmp/test-fails.pp, line: 22, column: 5) on node instance.example.com", where line 22 column 5 is the tilde in `~>`.

Answer (score 1):

The issue is on the *right-hand-side* of the `~>` operator. Specifically, since the `if` fails it creates the `undef` value. The fix is to ensure that there is an `else` clause, eg for this case:

```
~> if ($encryption_key != undef) and ($encryption_key != '') {
   file { $keyfile:
    content => $encryption_key,
    path    => $keyfile,
    owner   => 'database',
    group   => 'database',
    mode    => '0600',
    require => File[$ramdisk],
  }
} else {
  file { $keyfile:
    ensure  => absent,
  }
}
```

So not only will Puppet not write the file if the ramdisk is not mounted, it will delete any copy there created by other methods.

Comment: The suggested code does not express what the OP seems to intend.  Managing a file to be absent is not at all the same thing as leaving it unmanaged.

Comment: TBH, I don't really care if the file is there or not when the ram disk is not mounted. But I don't want puppet to install it if not ramdisk. This was something to do. Your other answer is valid, but I found no good Google results for the error message mentioned and wanted to memorialize my findings about the error.

Answer (score 0):

Although `if` statements do produce values, those values are not necessarily suitable right-hand operands for the `~>` operator.  In particular, `undef` will be the value produced by your `if` statement when its condition evaluates to `false`, and that is not an acceptable operand for any of the chaining operators.

There are several ways you could approach the problem, some of which depend on what you really intend, but as a matter of style, I think it's poor form to use an `if` statement as an operand of a chaining arrow under any circumstances.

If indeed you simply want to manage file `$keyfile` only when the condition is satisfied, as you seem to show in your example, then the most natural solution would be to use the appropriate relationship metaparameter instead of a chaining arrow:

```
mount { $ramdisk:
  # ...
}
# no chaining arrow here
if ($encryption_key != undef) and ($encryption_key != '') {
   file { $keyfile:
    # ...
    require   => File[$ramdisk],
    # Like this:
    subscribe => Mount[$ramdisk],
  }
}
```

Putting the metaparameter on the resource that is included only conditionally gives you a relationship that is declared only when that resource is declared.  Also, it's simple and clear.